# Python If its same output dont send msg

Tags: python, json, api, bots, discord.py

I made a **discord** bot that sends every 120 sec **transactions** from one ethereum addrs but i dont want to send same stuff over and over so if it send **USDT** token and Again in **120 sec try** **USDT** to just skip it until it got new thing is that possble or not?
code:

```
import requests
import sys 
import json
import discord
import time
btoken = "mytoken"
result=requests.get('https://api.ethplorer.io/getAddressHistory/0x3f5ce5fbfe3e9af3971dd833d26ba9b5c936f0be?apiKey=freekey&type=transfer')
result.status_code
result.text
result.json()
results = "soon:tm:"

def price_of_gas(inp):
    def recursive_function(inp):
        if type(inp) is list:
            for i in inp:
                ans = recursive_function(i)
                if ans!=None: return ans
        elif type(inp) is dict:
            if 'name' in inp: return inp['name']
            for i in inp:
                ans = recursive_function(inp[i])
                if ans!=None: return ans
        else: return None
    ans = recursive_function(inp)
    return ans if ans else "Could NOT find the new token tx"
print (price_of_gas(result.json()))

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)
    

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content == '.get':
            await message.channel.send('Alert! Alert! Buy')
            await message.channel.send(result.json()['operations'][0]['tokenInfo']['symbol'])
            await message.channel.send(result.json()['operations'][0]['tokenInfo']['address'])
            
            print ('get command was tryed')
        else:
            print ('comand not found')
            
        if message.content == '.help':
            await message.channel.send("try .get")
            print ('help command was tryed')
        if message.content == '.stop':
           await message.channel.send('Bye...')
           print('bye') 
           sys.exit()
        if message.content == '.start':
         while True:
              # Code executed here
              print ('done')
              price_of_gas(result.json())
              print (price_of_gas(result.json()))
              await message.channel.send(price_of_gas(result.json())) 
              time.sleep(120)    

              
           
        
#print(result.json()['operations'][0]['tokenInfo']['name'])
#print(result.json()['operations'][0]['tokenInfo']['symbol'])
#print(result.json()['operations'][0]['tokenInfo']['address'])

#print (result.json()['tokenSymbol'])
#print (result.text)
print ('done no errors')

print ('done no errors with check data')
client = MyClient()
client.run(btoken)
   


        
              


print ('done no errors 2')
```

so if user type .start bot will start while loop that sends newest tx from selected addrs but problem is it will send same stuff i just need some if statment in while loop or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You shoudn't use the `requests` module (it's blocking), you should use `aiohttp` instead
2. You also shoudn't use `time.sleep` as it also blocks the whole thread. You should use `asyncio.sleep`. (If you still stay with `time.sleep` you're not going to be able to use the bot when it's "sleeping")

Answering your question, you can simply have a variable with the value of the previous price/value and check if the new message is the same, if it's not - send it

```py
while True:
    price = price_of_gas(result.json())
    # Checking if the `previous_price` var exists
    if hasattr(self, "previous_price"): 
        # If yes, comparing the values
        if self.previous_price != price: 
            # If they're not the same, send the message
            await message.channel.send(f"Current price: {price}")
            self.previous_price = price # Updating the variable

    else:
        # If the `previous_price` var doesn't exists, creating it
        self.previous_price = price

    await asyncio.sleep(120) # Remember to import asyncio
```

Making HTTP requests with `aiohttp`

```py
import aiohttp

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("URL") as resp:
            data = await resp.json()

    # Note: you should create ONE session per application
```

EDIT:

If you want to use blocking functions (like the `price_of_gas`) you can use the next method

```py
await self.loop.run_in_executor(None, price_of_gas, result.json())
```

More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html?highlight=loop%20run_in_executor#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)